# VB6 How to pass variables to different form

Tags: vb6

I am starting with 1 form and 1 class. The idea is to set some class members and then call those members from a different form. I can't even set the values for some reason. We have a project done in VB6 and unfortunately, there is no chance to upgrade and am stuck on VB6.

**Form1:**

```
Public SomeClassObj As New SomeClass

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Set SomeClassObj.Test1 = 1
  Set SomeClassObj.Test2 = 2
  Call SomeClassObj.Test
End Sub
```

**Class SomeClass:**

```
Public Test1 As Integer
Public Test2 As Integer

Public Sub Test()
  MsgBox Test1
  MsgBox Test2
End Sub
```

The error I get is "invalid use of property" and stops on Command1_Click: ".Test1 ="

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should remove `Set` keywords - you are not assigning objects.

Comment: That fixes it, Arvo, thank you. If you want to post this as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `Set` keywords - you are not assigning objects/references.

Comment: Thank you Arvo. Can you answer another question, either here or in chat? I'm attempting to post another  question but SO must have implemented a 90 minute quota.